# Provider hosted app on Office365 not working

Tags: error, office-365, sharepoint-addin

I have created Provider Hosted App. And Checked locally on my machine that if it is working or not. It was working properly on my machine.
I create a self-signed certificate for deploying my app on my machine as shown in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/fp179901.aspx) site.
Now when it was working properly I tried to publish my app on Office365.

I added my app into my Online Site of Office365 and followed all necessary steps for publishing.

But when I Open My app after adding it I just got error that `404: Page Not Found` 
On the page that is the Start Page of my app. It was not finding the page which I added in my app as a Start page.

[image: This image is of error when I run app on Office365 site]

-> Do any one know how to solve this.?
-> When we publish Provider Hosted App don't it get all the pages installed that we have created for it on Web Site where we have published App.?
-> Can I add different .aspx Pages to an Provider Hosted app.?

Comment: What's the URL it's trying to go to? Is it your local dev URL or a publically accessible URL?

Comment: No it is my Office365 Development URL.

Comment: Ignoring O365 for a moment, can you browse to the provider-host URL?

Comment: I don't know about that sir. Which will be the Provider Host Url?

Comment: I am totally new for SharePoint App Development so I just know what I have seen on the time Development and Other what I have searched.

Comment: The URL above should be the provider hosted URL, when you go to the app, it redirects you to your app. Try accessing it directly, and without all of the URL parameters. Try different pages, or no pages, just domain.com/

Comment: I have Checked What the domain url it is getting is the Main URL of my Domain that is where I want to host my app(O365 url) and it is working properly. And after that domain "/Pages/PollQuestionView.aspx" is the page on which my App should be redirect. But that page is not found..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8992/discussion-between-rahul-gokani-and-david-lozzi)

Comment: I've written 1 provider hosted app, and it deployed successfully. I was hoping to check the DNS of your App to ensure it's setup correctly. Unfortunately I'm not sure where to take it from here, sounds like your app isn't deployed to your host properly.

Comment: Hello sir. I have Deployed my app On Premises. And it was deployed successfully. And then I published my app in that it Created .app file I put that file in my SharePoint Online's App catalog. And from there I install it on my Online Site.

Comment: A provider hosted app is running outside of SharePoint Online / Office 365. When you tested your app locally, it was running in visual studio on your dev machine? Have your deployed your web project on a publically available url, where anyone can reach it? Even SharePoint hosted apps run outside the SharePoint site where it's installed.

Comment: Please do use chat rather than comments if this is really a back-and-forth conversation. Thanks [mod].

Comment: @PetterSkodvin-Hvammen : Hey, thank you for the Replay an yes I have tested in my dev machine using visual studio. And also I have published it for Office365. And In that I added my app and run it and got this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a website in Azure and publish the appweb file there. Then make sure that the app file is pointing to that site which will be .azurewebsites.net. Also make sure that the app has the relevent rights and permissions

Answer (score 0):

You needed to configure the Azure website with the client id and client secret. As explained to the following [blog](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/07/deploying-sp2013-provider-hosted.html)